# how to access values returned by google feed api in page load?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-feed-api

am currently using google feed api to get feed links dynamically. am trying to use the results returned by the api to create rss feed for my website..Now the problem is api function call takes place only after the page load so i cant access the url values returned by the api in page load function..

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAxII5vpTAk5gatTPIMAFoCxStIDvCAqMV0_KActMytIL1qEezxxQeBqRzIurcFfnrUgG2YMlC07VgbQ"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load("feeds", "1", { "callback": OnLoad });

        function OnLoad() {
            // Query for president feeds on cnn.com
            var query = 'atlanta bridal shows';
            google.feeds.findFeeds(query, findDone);
        }

        function findDone(result) {
            // Make sure we didn't get an error.
            if (!result.error) {
                // Get content div
                var content = document.getElementById('content');
                var html = '';
                var submenu = new Array()
                // Loop through the results and print out the title of the feed and link to
                // the url.
                for (var i = 0; i < result.entries.length; i++) {
                    var entry = result.entries[i];
                    html += '<p><a href="' + entry.url + '">' + entry.title + '</a></p>';
                    submenu[i] = entry.url;
                }
                content.innerHTML = html;

                document.getElementById('<%= Hidden1.ClientID %>').value = submenu;
            }
        }

        google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" runat="server" ondatabinding="Hidden1_DataBinding" 
        onunload="Hidden1_Unload" onvaluechanged="Hidden1_ValueChanged" />
<div id="content"></div>

</asp:Content>
```

pageload event:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string path = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
               VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/user/feed.htm");

        Stream stream = client.OpenRead(path);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();

          }
```

What should i do to access the values returned by the api in page load??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to create `feed.htm` and put above code in it.

feed.htm (which is located at root of web-app)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAxII5vpTAk5gatTPIMAFoCxStIDvCAqMV0_KActMytIL1qEezxxQeBqRzIurcFfnrUgG2YMlC07VgbQ"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("feeds", "1", { "callback": OnLoad });

    function OnLoad() {
        // Query for president feeds on cnn.com
        var query = 'atlanta bridal shows';
        google.feeds.findFeeds(query, findDone);
    }

    function findDone(result) {
        // Make sure we didn't get an error.
        if (!result.error) {
            // Get content div
            var content = document.getElementById('content');
            var html = '';
            var submenu = new Array()
            // Loop through the results and print out the title of the feed and link to
            // the url.
            for (var i = 0; i < result.entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = result.entries[i];
                html += '<p><a href="' + entry.url + '">' + entry.title + '</a></p>';
                submenu[i] = entry.url;
            }
            content.innerHTML = html;

            document.getElementById('<%= Hidden1.ClientID %>').value = submenu;
        }
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Then after in `page_load` event of .aspx page use `System.Net.WebClient` class methods to request the `feed.htm`.

TestFeed.aspx (which is located at root of web-app)

Markup:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string path = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/feed.htm");

        Stream stream = client.OpenRead(path);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        //To view the result
        Label1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: how to specify open OpenRead url for a local machine

Comment: its just returns the content of the page not the feed value obtained from api

Comment: i have edited the code please go through it.. it works fine and am able to get feed results but am unable to capture the values in pageload event

Comment: @karthi - See the edited post. You may test the "feed.htm" by requesting or opening it in web-browser.

Comment: sorry for troubling u..htm page works fine .. but on running the aspx page the html page does not execute so its just returns the content (Javascript ) in the page

Comment: @karthi - Don't worry! Be sure that page "feed.htm" is located at the root of your web-app. If you created "feed.htm" under "abc" folder then change the path  VirtualPathUtility..ToAbsolute("~/abc/feed.htm");

Comment: :ya i have specified the path as you said .. but i doubt that with out executing the html page how can we get the feed results..sorry if i am wrong

Comment: @karthi -Method client.OpenRead(path) will request the "feed.htm". Can you post the .aspx page_load event code where the you have add WebClient code?

Comment: it works.....i was checking the values with a breakpoint near string content .thanks a lot...